# Google Dataflow with Python failed to install workflow: exit status 1

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-dataflow

My Google Dataflow job runs locally with local runner but fails building its package for running the pipeline with the `DataflowRunner`. I am having this issue on `apache-beam[gcp]==2.6.0` the same pipeline works on `apache-beam[gcp]==2.4.0`

My code works with the `DirectRunner` locally without any problem and building the package `python setup.py sdist --formats=tar` and installing that `pip install dist/my-package.tar` works as well.

The job fails with the error message:

```
Failed to install packages: failed to install workflow: exit status 1
```

This error is thrown after the following info logs which seem to indicate the system numpy in the dataflow container is missing METADATA

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.14.5.dist-info/METADATA'
```

```
Failed to report setup error to service: could not lease work item to report failure (no work items returned)
```

Based on the above numpy error I installed `numpy 1.14.5` which fixed my issue. I am still facing an issue of being unable to debug package setup as the exact way Dataflow builds its containers is quite opaque.

My issue is not with my `setup.py` as otherwise the `sdist` build shouldn't have worked. Dataflow's Docker image build process doesn't match `dataflow.gcr.io/v1beta3/python:2.6.0` as that image doesn't have numpy nor beam installed in it. With the lack of reproducible docker builds debugging workflows is difficult.

Some context around my workflow setup code:

I install `neuralcoref` library from https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref-models/releases/download/en_coref_lg-3.0.0/en_coref_lg-3.0.0.tar.gz with custom commands and the rest of my `setup.py` is:

```
...
REQUIRED_PACKAGES = [
    'six==1.12.0',
    'dill==0.2.9',
    'apache-beam[gcp]==2.6.0',
    'spacy==2.0.13',
    'requests==2.18.4',
    'unidecode==1.0.22',
    'tqdm==4.23.3',
    'lxml==4.2.1',
    'python-dateutil==2.7.3',
    'textblob==0.15.1',
    'networkx==2.1',
    'flashtext==2.7',
    'annoy==1.12.0',
    'ujson==1.35',
    'repoze.lru==0.7',
    'Whoosh==2.7.4',
    'python-Levenshtein==0.12.0',
    'fuzzywuzzy==0.16.0',
    'attrs==19.1.0',
    # 'scikit-learn==0.19.1',# preinstalled in dataflow
    # 'pandas==0.23.0',# preinstalled in dataflow
    # 'scipy==1.1.0',# preinstalled in dataflow

]

setuptools.setup(
    name='myproject',
    version='0.0.6',
    description='my project',
    install_requires=REQUIRED_PACKAGES,
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    cmdclass={
        # Command class instantiated and run during pip install scenarios.
        'build': build,
        'CustomCommands': CustomCommands,
    }
)
```

My local `requirements.txt` is:

```
six==1.12.0
apache-beam[gcp]==2.6.0
spacy==2.0.13
requests==2.18.4
unidecode==1.0.22
tqdm==4.23.3
lxml==4.2.1
python-dateutil==2.7.3
textblob==0.15.1
networkx==2.1
flashtext==2.7
annoy==1.12.0
ujson==1.35
repoze.lru==0.7
Whoosh==2.7.4
python-Levenshtein==0.12.0
fuzzywuzzy==0.16.0
attrs==19.1.0
scikit-learn==0.19.1
pandas==0.23.0
scipy==1.1.0
```

The full error message is:

```
{
 insertId:  "7107501484934866351:1025729:0:380041"  
 jsonPayload: {
  line:  "boot.go:145"   
  message:  "Failed to install packages: failed to install workflow: exit status 1"   
 }
 labels: {
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_id:  "7107501484934866351"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_name:  "myjob-04170525-av5b-harness-0w5w"   
  compute.googleapis.com/resource_type:  "instance"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_id:  "2019-04-17_05_25_10-4738638106522967260"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/job_name:  "myjob"   
  dataflow.googleapis.com/region:  "us-central1"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/myproject/logs/dataflow.googleapis.com%2Fworker-startup"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-04-17T13:21:37.786576023Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   job_id:  "2019-04-17_05_25_10-4738638106522967260"    
   job_name:  "myjob"    
   project_id:  "myproject"    
   region:  "us-central1"    
   step_id:  ""    
  }
  type:  "dataflow_step"   
 }
 severity:  "CRITICAL"  
 timestamp:  "2019-04-17T13:21:19.954714Z"  
}
```

Comment: Could you check the worker startup logs for error messages. They might be logged as info messages but will contain errors, prior to the error message you have in the question.

Comment: @SzereDyeri looking at the relevant info logs it seems the issue is stemming from numpy missing METADATA folder or file at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy-1.14.5.dist-info/METADATA in the Dataflow Docker container

Comment: Dataflow's docker image for 2.6.0 should have numpy 1.14.5 installed. (See this list, documenting dependencies since 2.6.0 - https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#sdk-for-python) - In your case, are you seeing that numpy is not correctly installed?

Comment: Yes based on this error message I identified numpy 1.4.5 was not correctly installed

Comment: OK. In that case it makes sense that re-installation of numpy fixes your issue. Would you be able to use a newer Beam version? 2.6 is fairly old and 2.11 is the latest version.

Comment: I am in the process of migrating to newer versions of beam though migration is challenging as it is not easy to reproducible build the Python environment used by Dataflow

Comment: Dataflow's worker dependencies are documented (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/sdk-worker-dependencies#sdk-for-python). In addition you could manually pull the container and inspect it.

Comment: Thanks for the doc link. The pulled container doesn't have all the packages in the documentation btw so in the end I sshed into a machine while running the pipeline and ran `pip freeze`. A common failure pattern seems to me is around misconfigured package METADATA in the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to configure the version of beam in your setup.py? I don't believe that will work. The version of dataflow needs to match the version you are running the job from.

Each version of Beam has its own container on dataflow. The dataflow container for 2.6.0 can be pulled from here: dataflow.gcr.io/v1beta3/python:2.6.0 There is a significant difference between 2.4.0 and 2.6.0, including the verison of pip.

To help you debug further, please add a copy of your setup.py. It would also be useful to know what version of apache-beam is installed (from `pip list`).

Comment: Added `requirements.txt` and `setup.py`. 

If I want my Python runner and execution environment would I not need to add beam within `setup.py`? In my use case one the issues is around spacy is I am dependent on specific versions of dill which will clash with higher version of beam.

I will also try and build the package with `setup.py` using the relevant dataflow container to see if the package build process fails to cause the workflow installation failure.